# Asp.net DataAnnotations Regex evaluate a Char based on the Char before

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to write a regex that captures a year and week. For an ASP.net ViewModel.

Here is the Expression I'm using now.

```
 [RegularExpression(@"[\d]{4}-[0-5]\d", ErrorMessage = "Work Week Requires 4 digit year - 2 Week.  e.g. 2019-09")]
```

This does most of what I want it to do but there are a few cases it is not handling.

Here is what I'm attempting to capture/Reject

```
2001-01  good
2001-10  good
2001-01  good
2001-10  good
2010-1   good
6502-9   good
4657-09  good
2003-01  good
2056-53  good
2056-54  bad
2068-60  bad 
5416-00  bad 
2015-0   bad

10000-15 would be nice to catch but I'm Ok with this code breaking 8000 years from now
```

I have created a regex101 with this problem https://regex101.com/r/iL5rpY/2

**Problem**

I don't how to evaluate a Char based on the Char before.

**Question**

How do I create a regular expression that captures all text versions of integers 1 to 53?

Comment: Probably, you want [`^\d{4}-(?:0?[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])$`](https://regex101.com/r/MKyZAT/1). Or [`^\d{4,5}-(?:0?[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])$`](https://regex101.com/r/MKyZAT/2). Or, considering bonus ones, try [`^\d{4,5}-0*(?:[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])$`](https://regex101.com/r/MKyZAT/3).

Comment: You could match 1-53 using [`^(?:5[0-3]|[1-4][0-9]|[1-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/JFX6IP/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was fast i did not know about the Non-captureing group that is help full

Comment: updated link with bonus points

Comment: @Thefourthbird ok that is good but does not handle leading 0's like Wiktor comment.

Comment: Ah of course, then it could be [`^(?:5[0-3]|[1-4][0-9]|0?[1-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/C3oPh0/1/) with an optional leading zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^0*\d{4,5}-0*(?:[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i1uh20/1).

**Details**

- `^`  - start of string
- `0*` - zero or more `0`s
- `\d{4,5}` - 4 or 5 digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `0*` - zer or more `0`s
- `(?:[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])` - either a digit from `1` to `9`, or a digit from `1` to `4` and then any digit or `5` followed with `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: just tested in this is now being deployed in production. This is what I needed.